# PostgreSQL: best way to create a generated column based on summed results from other columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm brand new to PostgreSQL, so this question is probably elementary for experienced folks.

I created a test database with a table named `Activity` that looks as follows:

```
Manufacturer     Region       Model         Orders     Sales   
BMW              Americas     3 Series      58390      47092
BMW              Americas     4 Series      31938      28474
BMW              Americas     5 Series      13730      10837
BMW              Americas     7 Series       9372       6493
Audi             Europe       A3            60483      50381
Audi             Europe       A4            49302      39303
Audi             Europe       A5            50319      49001
Audi             Europe       A6             9101       4688
```

I would like to create a "generated" and stored column named `OrdersToTradesRatio` (which is the ratio of orders to sales **summed by region**).

Using the data above, the `OrdersToSales` would be:

```
OrdersToSales
1.22104         <----- Mercedes --- (58390 + 31938 + 13730 + 9372) / (47092 + 28474 + 10837 + 6493)
1.18017         <----- Audi ------- (60483 + 49302 + 50319 + 9101) / (50381 + 39303 + 49001 + 4688)
```

Incorporating the calculated `OrdersToSales` column, the table might look as follows:

```
Manufacturer     Region       Model         Orders     Sales     OrdersToSales  
BMW              Americas     3 Series      58390      47092      <null>
BMW              Americas     4 Series      31938      28474      <null>
BMW              Americas     5 Series      13730      10837      <null>
BMW              Americas     7 Series       9372       6493      <null>
BMW              Americas     <null>        <null>     <null>    1.22104
Audi             Europe       A3            60483      50381      <null>
Audi             Europe       A4            49302      39303      <null>
Audi             Europe       A5            50319      49001      <null>
Audi             Europe       A6             9101       4688      <null>
Audi             Europe       <null>        <null>     <null>    1.18017
```

Is this possible to create this `OrdersToSales` column as shown above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your version of Postgresql

Comment: Do *not* store such a column that would become invalid if other rows are modified. Redundancy like that is a problem. Calculate the value on `SELECT`.

Comment: @Akhilesh Mishra -- I'm using PostgreSQL version 12.3.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Completely agree. This should be as a result of `Select` only. Do not store this in table.

Comment: @equanimity Try `ROLLUP` grouping. you will get slight different output but it is relevant in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select "Manufacturer","Region","Model","Orders","Sales", null as "OrdersToSales" from "Activity"

union all

select "Manufacturer", "Region", null,null,null, round(sum("Orders")/sum("Sales"),5) 
from "Activity" 
group by "Manufacturer", "Region"

order by "Manufacturer","Region","Model", "OrdersToSales" desc
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8zvqG6B3gHwdfR46p3xD5h/1)

You should give a try to `ROLLUP`  if it suits your requirement

Comment: You should use `sum` as a window function here and without `GROUP BY`, then you could get something like the output that OP wants.

Comment: Running @Akhilesh Mishra's code as is, I get an error message stating:  `ERROR:  relation "activity" does not exist
LINE 1: select *, null as "ordertosales" from activity
                                              ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 39`

Comment: Does `Activity` (the table name is capitalized) need to be surrounded in double quotation marks and/or prefaced by "public."?  (again, I'm brand new to this and still getting used to the syntax!)

Comment: Also, do the column names need to be capitalized?

Comment: Yes if your table/schema/column names are not in lower case then you have to put in Double Quotation i.e. `"Activity"`

Comment: Putting everything in double quotations eliminates the error message above, but now exposes this error message:  `ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns`

Comment: That error comes on line 5 of your code, @Akhilesh Mishra.  `LINE 5: select "Manufacturer", "Region", null,null,null, sum("Orders...`

Comment: I have updated the answer with exact columns of your question. now try this. also compare the names with your actual schema.Added Example Fiddle also. Let me know the problem if any

Comment: Thank you, @Akhilesh Mishra.  This works now.  How would you incorporate the `ROLLUP` clause?